# Topology induced by $d(x,y) = \sum 2^{-i} \max \lbrace d_i(x_i,y_i) , 1 \rbrace$ on $\prod X_i$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X_i, d_i) $ be a sequence of metric spaces.
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 2^{-i} \max \lbrace d_i(x_i,y_i) , 1 \rbrace$$
is a distance on $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} X_i.$ Is the topology induced by the distance the same as the product topology?

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: If we decompose the argument a little bit, $d(x,y)=\sum 2^{-k}d_k(x_k,y_k)$ endows $\prod X_k$ with the product topology, provided that $d$ is well-defined (as in the case that the $d_k$'s are mutually bounded). And also, if $(X,d)$ is any metric space, $\tilde{d}(x,y):=\max\{d(x,y),1\}$ is another metric on $X$ endowing it with the same topology, which happens to be bounded. (So, by the way, is $\hat{d}(x,y):=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$, another popular choice.)

Comment: Actually, to get the product topology, you need to replace $\max$ by $\min$.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: oh, that's embarrassing; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> $d(x,y)=\sum 2^{-k}d_k(x_k,y_k)$ endows $\prod X_k$ with the product topology, provided that $d$ is well-defined (as in the case that the $d_k$'s are mutually bounded). And also, if $(X,d)$ is any metric space, $\tilde{d}(x,y):=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$ is another metric on $X$ endowing it with the same topology, which happens to be bounded. (So, by the way, is $\hat{d}(x,y):=\dfrac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$, another popular choice.)

--  [Jonathan Y.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671443/topology-induced-by-dx-y-sum-2-i-max-lbrace-d-ix-i-y-i-1-rbrace#comment1410888_671443)